# Marshalling PDouble (C# -> Delphi)

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, marshalling

I've got an unmanaged DLL file written in Delphi, containing a function with the following definition:

```
function F(tgran: integer; inputs: PDouble; goutp, outputs, toutp: PDouble): integer; stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';
```

I've written an Adapter in C# that should help me consume it.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(APIAdapter.Convention)]
public delegate int FDelegate(int tgran, IntPtr inputs, IntPtr goutp, IntPtr outputs, IntPtr toutp);

public class APIAdapter : IDisposable
    {
        public const string DllName = "mydll.dll";
        public const CallingConvention Convention = CallingConvention.StdCall;
        public FDelegate F;
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, String procname);

        private IntPtr _dllHandle;
        public APIAdapter()
        {
            _dllHandle = LoadLibrary(DllName);

            F = (FDelegate)GetFunction<CalcCavSpDelegate>("F");           
        }

        private Delegate GetFunction<T>(string procName)            
        {
            IntPtr procAddress = GetProcAddress(_dllHandle, procName);
            return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procAddress, typeof(T));
        }

        ~APIAdapter()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            { 
            }

            while (FreeLibrary(_dllHandle))
            { 
            }
        }
    }
```

The usage is pretty straightforward:

```
using(var api = new APIAdapter())
{
  // Call API functions
}
```

The problem is an AccessViolationException that happens within the DLL file.

I've tried to pass the PDouble variables as `double[], double* (unsafe code), IntPtr`. It's the same story regardless of the method I choose. I've tried to substantially increase the size of the arrays passed in to exclude errors with array indexing - AccessViolation exception again.

What is the proper way of passing a PDouble into an unmanaged Delphi DLL file?

Comment: Impossible to give code for this since we don't know how big the arrays are and who's responsibility it is to allocate them. Also, I urge you to rewrite the code with `DllImport` so that the question can focus on the real issue.

Comment: It is also rather astounding that you include all the boilerplate linking code but omit the code that actually calls the native DLL!

Comment: I'll update the post above soon (tm)

Comment: To answer your question in short, arrays are allocated C#-side. The .dll is aware of their size.

Comment: Does the dll use the pointers after the function you called returns?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do away with all the `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and `FreeLibrary` complexity by simply using `DllImport` attribute. Though, I can say that I am not aware about any specific reason of why you chose to go this way.

Anyway, you can simply include `ref double doubleArg` in your declaration to pass PDouble. There should be no need of `IntPtr` here.

Comment: That's fine for a scalar, but these are arrays.

Comment: yes, exactly, I'm passing arrays :/ - it appears that the problem persists with PByte in functions I've not listed here, as well.

Comment: I thought he was trying to pass pointer to double :)...will see if I can figure out how to do this for arrays

Comment: Have you tried using MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray) attribute?

Comment: Why would that differ from default marshalling for double[]?